# Why child process is not printing the statement?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am running the `do_work` function 5 times on different processors. I am aware that each process has different memory space and it runs the entire piece of this code except what is written inside `if __name__=='__main__'` On running it, why hello1 and hello are only printed once? As each of them are mentioned outside `if __name__=='__main__'`?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
import time
from multiprocessing import process

def do_work():
    print('start_work')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('sleep_over')
    p = 0
    for j in range(200):
        p+=1
    print('finished_work')
    
print('hello1')

if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        t = Process(target=do_work,args=())
        t.start()
        
print('hello2')
```

Comment: What OS are you using? There are important differences between Windows and Unix regarding how they spawn new processes

Comment: I am using windows and running the code on VS code

Comment: You are not actually creating new processes. You are creating ***threads***. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)

Comment: Using `from multiprocessing import Process` instead of the `dummy` import you used gives your expected output (on Windows)